# Display thumbnail of the Custom Option File upload field in the cart in magento

Tags: magento, file-upload

I have a Photo Upload Cake product, where the user can upload an image that he would like to see on the cake he orders.
To do this I have added a Custom Option on this product. Here the customer can upload the image that he wants to see on the cake.

When this product is added to the cart, the link to this file is available for download. However instead of the link to the file I can display this file image thumbnail instead?

What changes would I need to make for it?

Thanks,
Neet

Answer (score 1):

Just stick to this tutorial, it tells you everything you need to know:

http://www.atwix.com/magento/how-to-resize-images/